# Select2 4.0.0 select before Ajax response

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I want the user, when using the input to be able to :

1 : Fetch data from server when typing, then select according to proposition

2 : Or If the user knows what he wants he should be able to type exactly what he wants before the data is fetched and then press enter

The requirement 1: works perfectly. The fact is I really don't know how to handle the 2. Currently when the user is typing, he can,t press enter before the data is fetched. I looked at the doc trying to find some kind of options enabling this but it seems like there is not.

If you ever had to implement that kind of behaviors I am curious about it. I have a few tweak in minds but I'd really like to use a native behavior.

Comment: I am curious about who can help you with this! I am having the same issue.